# The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken

Tags: linq

Whats wrong with this code and how can I fix it ?

I am using .net 3.5, Sql Server 2008 Express version an Windows 7 64.
I am getting this error:

[UpdateFileStatus] ERROR -
System.InvalidOperationException: The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.Initialize()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEInitialize(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateActive.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at StorageQuest.Ovm.Connection.Dal.FilesDal.GetFile(Guid fileId, Int32 fileFolderId, Int32 fileFolderFileId, Int16 fileVersion)
   at StorageQuest.Ovm.Connection.Dal.FilesDal.UpdateFileStatus(Guid fileId, Int32 fileFolderId, Int32 fileFolderFileId, Int16 fileVersion, Guid discId, FileStatus fileStatus)
   at StorageQuest.Ovm.Connection.Bll.FilesBll.UpdateFileStatus(Guid fileId, Int32 fileFolderId, Int32 fileFolderFileId, Int16 fileVresion, Guid discId, FileStatus fileStatus)

```
        public bool UpdateFileStatus(Guid fileId, int fileFolderId, int fileFolderFileId, short fileVresion, Guid discId, FileStatus fileStatus)
    {
        FilesDal filesDAL = new FilesDal(this.connection);

        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope transcope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.Zero ))
            {
                bool result = filesDAL.UpdateFileStatus(fileId, fileFolderId, fileFolderFileId, fileVresion, discId, fileStatus);
                transcope.Complete();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlConn.LogConnection.Error(null, ex);
        }

        return false;
    }

        internal bool UpdateFileStatus(Guid fileId, int fileFolderId, int fileFolderFileId, short fileVersion, Guid discId, FileStatus fileStatus)
    {
        File file = null;

        try
        {
            file = GetFile(fileId, fileFolderId, fileFolderFileId, fileVersion);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlConn.LogConnection.Error(null, ex);
        }

        if (file == null)
            return false;

        file.FileDiscID = discId;
        file.FileStatus = (byte)fileStatus;

        try
        {
            return SaveFile(file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlConn.LogConnection.Error(null, ex);
        }

        return false;
    }

        internal File GetFile(Guid fileId, int fileFolderId, int fileFolderFileId, short fileVersion)
    {
        using (FilesDataContext fileDC = new FilesDataContext(this.connection)
            {
                DeferredLoadingEnabled = false,
                CommandTimeout = 0
            })

            return fileDC.Files.FirstOrDefault(
                    f => f.FileID.Equals(fileId) &&
                         f.FileFolderID.Equals(fileFolderId) &&
                         f.FileFolderFileID.Equals(fileFolderFileId) &&
                         f.FileVersion.Equals(fileVersion)
                            );
    }

        internal bool SaveFile(File file)
    {
        ChangeSet changeSet = null;
        int changeCount = 0;

        using (FilesDataContext fileDC = new FilesDataContext(this.connection)
            {
                DeferredLoadingEnabled = false,
                CommandTimeout = 0
            })
        {
            if (file.FileRowVersion == null)  //insert a file
            {
                fileDC.Files.InsertOnSubmit(file);
                changeSet = fileDC.GetChangeSet();
                changeCount = changeSet.Inserts.Count;
            }
            else                              //updates a file
            {
                fileDC.Files.Attach(file, true);
                changeSet = fileDC.GetChangeSet();
                changeCount = changeSet.Updates.Count;
            }

            try
            {
                fileDC.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (ChangeConflictException cce)
            {
                fileDC.Log = Console.Out;
                Console.WriteLine(cce);
                SqlConn.LogConnection.Error(null, cce);
                //SqlConn.ChangeConflictException(fileDC);
                return false;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
            {
                SqlConn.LogConnection.Error(null, ioe);
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SqlConn.LogConnection.Error(null, ex);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return !changeCount.Equals(0) ? true : false;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Error is thrown when I call GetFile()

Comment: Try to remove the TransactionScope. You don't need it, because only in `SaveFile` you are writing to the database and there is only one `SubmitChanges` there.

Comment: Do you mean to move GetFile() out side the TransactionScope ?

Comment: No, remove it, remove the `using` statement.

Comment: I will do and wait to get feedback from our customer.